# Hosting a website

Tags: postgresql, configuration

I'm planning to host a website. I'm assuming, with time, I may have 100,000 users 2-5% would be online at a time.

I'm planning to go for postgresql.

The data I'm expecting that users will upload will be binary files including photographs mostly and limited character texts.

`Assuming 2000 users online and 1000 users uploading photographs and exchanging text messages what should be the server configuration should I need. I'm planning to take a static IP and buy own servers as of now.`

Please comment, as I do not have much knowledge about web stuff. I can do it on a computer on a tomcat webserver, but how is it done at large scale, please advise.

`Please comment of the decision of PostgreSql. What if number of users increased to more than expected, and things like that`

Comment: It would take me at least a couple of days work to model the workload then probably 2 more to work on the architecture, and I'd need a lot more information than you've provided. And you expect me to teach you how to do all this yourself in a short post here, starting from the point of "not have much knowledge about web stuff". Couldn't you try something simpler like brain surgery or building moon rockets?

Comment: As above - you want to build a web architecture that can serve 2000 simultaneous users and "do not have much knowledge about web stuff"? Why are you asking about databases specifically?

Comment: @growse: Yeah web stuff, I mean distributed architecture and new technologies like NoSql and stuff. Well, I need an efficient database for fast lookup, but which should be scaleable. I don't know if postgresql is a fine choice. I'm fine with partition DBs to different tables and make them monitored by instances of diiferent DBs under different server hardwares. What I need is a **not very accurate answer** like: Start with intel xeon quad core it will support X number of users for photo uploads and simple texts  or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of sounds similar to the load of the dutch site tweakers.net, and they have a rack full of load balancers, failover nodes, SAN storage, database replication, etc. I don't know if you're going to make it with one machine... And if you don't know much about web stuff, you may be out of your league.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to host facebook. Its website with 0 users. It would take time for anybody to start thinking of registering with a new website. I think for coming 6 months I can host it with an instance of MySql, tomcat and may be an Intel Xeon. Rest will be done with time.